# bitwise-ANDing with 0xff is important?

Tags: java, byte, bitwise-operators, short, bitwise-and

Doesn't bitwise-ANDing with 0xff essentially mean getting the same value back, for that matter, in this code?

```
byte[] packet = reader.readPacket();
short sh;
sh = packet[1];
sh &= 0xFF;
System.out.print(sh+" ");
```

Weirdly, I get a -1 if that ANDing is not included but a 255 when included Could someone explain the reason?

As I see it 0xff is just 1111 1111. Isn't it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, `0xff` is just `1111 1111`.  But this is attempting to display the unsigned byte value, even though in Java `byte`s are signed.  The value `0xff` is `-1` for a signed `byte`, but it's `255` in a `short`.

When a `byte` value of `0xff` is read, printing the value would yield `-1`.  So it's assigned to a `short` which has a bigger range and can store `byte` values that would normally overflow to be a negative number as a `byte` as a positive integer, e.g. 144 as a `byte` is `0x90`, or -112, but it can be properly stored as `144` as a `short`.

So the `byte` value of `-1` is assigned to a `short`.  But what does that do?  A primitive widening conversion takes place, and negative values are sign-extended.  So `1111 1111` becomes `11111111 11111111`, still `-1`, but this time as a `short`.

Then the bitmask `0xff` (`00000000 11111111`) is used to get the last 8 bits out again:

```
  -1: 11111111 1111111
0xFF: 00000000 1111111
======================
 255: 00000000 1111111
```

It's just a way to get the unsigned `byte` value, by converting it to `short` and then masking out the original bits from the `byte`, to display it as an unsigned value.

Comment: I would give you an upvote, but you'll have to wait 24 minutes for an upvote from me. I am currently out of votes.

Comment: "So the byte value of -1 is assigned to a short. But what does that do? A primitive widening conversion takes place, and negative values are sign-extended."
 -- Excellent info.

"Then the bitmask 0xff (00000000 11111111) is used to get the last 8 bits out again"
-- huhh.. this is it.. Great thanks man...

Answer (score 3):

A `byte` has the range of -128 to 127.  This means some values are negative.  This is all the values where the top bit is set. So `(byte) 0xFF` is -1. When you use sign extension to make it a signed short, it becomes `(short) 0xFFFF` which is -1 as a short.  When you mask it, it chop off the extended bits and you treat the byte as if it where unsigned.

---

You don't get -1 unless your code is different to what you have in the question.

```
for (byte b = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b < Byte.MAX_VALUE; b++) {
    short s = b;
    s &= 0xff;
    System.out.println(b + " & 0xFF = " + s);
}
```

prints

```
-128 & 0xFF = 128
-127 & 0xFF = 129
....
-2 & 0xFF = 254
-1 & 0xFF = 255
0 & 0xFF = 0
1 & 0xFF = 1
...
125 & 0xFF = 125
126 & 0xFF = 126
```

Comment: In the question he does say "Weirdly, I get a -1 if that ANDing is **not** included". It seems to me like he knows WHAT happens but wants to know WHY.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Good point.  That is what I expected not weird at all.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks for having my back... You go me right.. I wanted to know WHY..

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming two's complement everywhere) Two things:

1. Bytes are signed, so `0xff` in a byte is equal to -1.
2. When going from a smaller data type to a larger data type (in this case, from a `byte` to a `short`), the *value* is kept. So, `sh = packet[1]` would set `sh` to `-1`, which is `0xffff`.

The thing with point #2 is that the "extra" bits get padded with 1s to keep the value whenever the original value is negative. The idea behind ANDing with `0xff` is that `sh` now contains `0x00ff`, with those "extra" 1s now removed.

Comment: "the value is kept. ".. that explains.. Thank you very much!