# Converting int to a byte array

Tags: java, bit-shift

Most bitshift solutions I have seen for converting an int to a byte array go like this:

```
return new byte [] {
    (byte) ((i >> 24) & 0xFF),
    (byte) ((i >> 16) & 0xFF),
    (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF),
    (byte) (i & 0xFF);
}
```

Why the & 0xFF??

Comment: That's bit-wise-and to turn the rest of the bits to 0.

Comment: Actually, it's probably not necessary if you will be casting to `(byte)`, since the cast does an implicit `& 0xFF` operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Does The Bitwise & (AND) Work In Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256644/how-does-the-bitwise-and-work-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061544/bitwise-anding-with-0xff-is-important

Comment: This will only generate the correct value if you want big endian... Shorter way to write the same code: `ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array()`

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths: Thanks, that was illuminating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`& 0xFF` is redundant and makes no difference in the given case

Comment: Agreed, along with some hints from the other question Graham Griffiths posted in his comments.