# What does the statement "out |= ( in & 0x7F ) << ( bytes++ * 7 );" mean in java?

Tags: java, minecraft, bungeecord

I was looking around the Minecraft's internal packet handling when I saw their VarInt reading code to read the packet length. As a java developer that does not have any course of java I was confused when I saw the statement `out |= ( in & 0x7F ) << ( bytes++ * 7 );`. Can someone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance!

If you want the whole code, just check the readVarInt function on BungeeCord's Github https://github.com/SpigotMC/BungeeCord/blob/master/protocol/src/main/java/net/md_5/bungee/protocol/DefinedPacket.java#L70 .

Comment: It means someone was into writing cryptic code.

Comment: What do you think it means? Have you looked into it at all?

Comment: Yeah, it isn't really that hard to read, if you take it piece by piece.

Comment: I haven't really messed with bit shifting and all that too much and yes, I've tried understanding it before posting. I hate people that just post questions like these without trying to understand first myself, so, I would not do that.

Comment: Umm.. what have you tried? Do you understand what the operators are doing? If not, have you tried googling? Start here &= http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html and here >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: (But it may not be obvious to the novice, even after the piece-by-piece interpretation, that it's simply taking a series of bytes and concatenating together the low-order 7 bits of each byte (assuming that `in` is reloaded from an array or whatever with each iteration).)

Comment: Oh and `*` is the multiplication operator.

Comment: I know that * is the multiplication operator :\

Anyway, thanks for your answer Hot Licks, I think I understand it now.

Comment: Useful link for understanding bitwise-ANDing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061544/bitwise-anding-with-0xff-is-important. You can also look at the other links for bitwise operators. If you need more help let us know -- perhaps you can clarify your question about what certain parts you don't understand? If it's how bytes work in general, maybe you can clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look at the link you included, but I would expect this line to be called in a loop to convert a number stored as a collection of 7-bit values back to an int or long.

The line you gave can be expanded to this:

```
int value = in & 0x7F;            // Grab 7 bits of data from "in"
int shift = bytes * 7;            // Calculate shift amount based on byte index
bytes = bytes+1;                  // Increment byte index (from bytes++)
out = out | (value << shift);     // Shift value and OR into output integer/long
```